# How to filter read and unread in-app notifications in REACT-NATIVE

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have two headings "Unread" and "Read" . I want the the Unread Notifications to go in beneath the Read notifications when open. the notification data is coming from an API.

There is a key in every notification called isRead with default value as false.
I tried :-

```
   const { mutate: markRead } = useMutation(markNotificationRead, {
    onSuccess: () => {},
    onError: () => {},
  });

  const handleDropDownToggle = () =>
    setIsDropDownOpen(!isDropDownOpen);
    toggleDropdown(item._id);
    !isDropDownOpen ? markRead(item?._id) : false
  };
```

Comment: There's a lot of code missing here. Why don't you sort it in your useMutation?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the notifications and sort them

```
  const notifications = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'New order received',
    description: 'Order #21034',
    read: false,
    date: '2020-09-12T07:30:00.000Z',
    type: 'order',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'New customer',
    description: 'Jessy Brown',
    read: false,
    date: '2020-09-12T07:30:00.000Z',
    type: 'user',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'New customer',
    description: 'Jessy Brown',
    read: true,
    date: '2020-09-12T07:30:00.000Z',
    type: 'user',
  },

]

// sort the notifications based on read status  (read: false first)
const sortedNotifications = notifications.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.read === b.read ? 0 : a.read ? 1 : -1;
}
);
```

so you can use the sorted notification on a flatlist to show them for example.